# Enable A Submit Button in Chrome

Tags: html, forms

what is the proper way to ENABLE a form submit button in HTML?  My form is currently disabled by Chrome and I need it to be enabled.

```
<div style="width:250px; float:left">
   <aside id="mailchimpsf_widget-2" class="widget widget_mailchimpsf_widget"><div class="widget-inner"> 

<div id="mc_signup">
<form method="post" action="#mc_signup" id="mc_signup_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="mc_submit_type" name="mc_submit_type" value="html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mcsf_action" value="mc_submit_signup_form" />
    <input type="hidden" id="_mc_submit_signup_form_nonce" name="_mc_submit_signup_form_nonce" value="d0bc38cc04" />        

<div class="mc_form_inside">
    <div class="updated" id="mc_message"></div><!-- /mc_message -->


<div class="mc_merge_var">
<label for="mc_mv_EMAIL" class="mc_var_label">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" size="18" value="" name="mc_mv_EMAIL" id="mc_mv_EMAIL" class="mc_input"/>
</div><!-- /mc_merge_var -->

    <div class="mc_signup_submit">
        <input type="submit" name="mc_signup_submit" id="mc_signup_submit" value="Keep Me Updated!" class="button" />
    </div><!-- /mc_signup_submit -->

</div><!-- /mc_form_inside -->
</form><!-- /mc_signup_form -->
</div><!-- /mc_signup_container -->
</div></aside>
            </div> <!--Left Floated Div-->
```

This button is also disabled somehow in IE9.  What is going on here?  I've never had this problem with forms.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "button" css class look like?

Comment: Doing a quick test, it seems it is not any of the css classes or ids. I would first remove this script: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.endingpovertytogether.org/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp/js/mailchimp.js?ver=1.2.10'></script>`, and see if it fixes the no submit problem.

Comment: Kovo, can you update your official answer.  I will vote it - I see the .js file contains the disabled function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, it is always enabled. Are you placing this submit button inside of a `<form>` tag?

You most likely have something else on the page interfering with your submit button.

Doing a quick test, it seems it is not any of the css classes or ids.

I would first remove this script: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.endingpovertytogether.org/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp/js/mailch‌​imp.js?ver=1.2.10'></script>`, and see if it fixes the no submit problem.

Comment: yes, it is a Mailchimp form placed in the header of this site.  http://www.endingpovertytogether.org.

Comment: I do not understand how to fix though.  thanks!  Would you mind providing this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a submit button in markup (to enable it simply remove the attribute):

```
<input type="button" id="my-button" value="Button" disabled="disabled" />
```

Or you can do it in script:

```
// disable
document.getElementById("my-button").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

//enable
document.getElementById("my-button").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

However, html elements are always enabled by default so check whether you have any script setting `input` children of an element to disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In endingpovertytogether.org's code:

```
<form method="post" action="#mc_signup" id="mc_signup_form" onSubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;">
..
<input type="submit" name="mc_signup_submit" id="mc_signup_submit" value="Keep Me Updated!" class="button" />
</form>
```

Remove `onSubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;"` in tag from

It's in script file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.endingpovertytogether.org/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp/js/mailch‌​imp.js?ver=1.2.10'></script>
```

Remove:

```
$('#mc_signup_submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

In `function mc_beforeForm()`

Comment: I shouldn't have posted that.  I edited my code and I still have the same problem.

Comment: It's in script file:`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.endingpovertytogether.org/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp/js/mailchimp.js?ver=1.2.10'></script>`

Comment: Zenofo, can you post this as an answer. It is working now, althougn now I'm dealing with Wordpress famous "Cheatin HuH?" message.

Comment: This is an answer,I've edited my answer,Hope this is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Is it inside a `<form>` tag?  That could lead to a submit button being disabled.  There is nothing to submit.